# Use "define" from another PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have file a.php with:

```
define('COLOR','blue');
```

and file b.php with:

```
include('/a.php');
echo COLOR;
```

... and "COLOR" is echoed. Is there something I need to do to carry the definition over?

File B is a WordPress functions file,  which is possibly the cause - but I want to check first that the PHP is correct, having never used define() before... Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `include`, you could use `require`. In this case, you would get a error, if the include file doesn't exists

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 6):

This should work just as you expect, however I think you have an issue on your include:

```
include('/a.php');
```

The leading slash anchors it to the root directory, which is almost certainly not what you want. I recommend using `require` instead so that you get an error if it fails:

```
require('a.php');
```

Comment: That would explain why it wouldn't be getting the CONSTANT definition, but shouldn't it be throwing an error instead of echoing the string "COLOR" instead?

Comment: Nope, just a WARNING, which most people (incorrectly) ignore.